# Reactjs Grid layout with defined number of columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, layout, grid

How can I implement a grid / card layout using javascript that has the following format:

```
<div class='x'>
  <div class='y'></div>
  <div class='y'></div>
  <div class='y'></div>
</div>
<div class='x'>
  <div class='y'></div>
  <div class='y'></div>
  <div class='y'></div>
</div>
```

The items of the column containers are retrieved by mapping over an array like so in a *FileList* component:

```
data.files.map(file => (
  <FileItem
    key={file.id}
    file={file}
    refresh={() => refetch()}
  />
))
```

I can pass in the `<div class='y'>` within the *FileItem* component. 
I just don't know how to implement the logic of the row container.

Essentially I want this:

```
<div class='x'>
  <div class='y'>FileItem 1</div>
  <div class='y'>FileItem 2</div>
  <div class='y'>FileItem 3</div>
</div>
<div class='x'>
  <div class='y'>FileItem 4</div>
  <div class='y'>FileItem 5</div>
  <div class='y'>FileItem 6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would only be possible if you partition your list in chunks of three beforehand and then iterate over the list of lists. [loash chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#chunk) does this. But in most of the cases you do not need this. It is better to only have one container and let the elements float into the next row by themself. In other words the alignment should be done with css not with html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be to use [_chunk()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#chunk) from the lodash library to create a list of chunks and then render each chunk in its own container:

```js
render() {
    const elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    const chunked = _chunk(elements, 3); // [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8]]

    return(
        {chunked.map(chunk => (
            <div className="row" key="???">
                {chunk.map(elem => (
                    <div className="col" key="???" >{elem}</div>
                ))}
            </div>
        ))}
    );
}
```

This will produce the following markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">4</div>
    <div class="col">5</div>
    <div class="col">6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">7</div>
    <div class="col">8</div>
</div>
```

The problems with this already start when you need to find a key for each of the row containers because react expects siblings of the same type to have a unique key.

A better way to get the same alignment is to only have one container and let the elements automatically float into the next "row" when the row is full. This can e.g. be achieved by using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/):

```
const numItemsPerRow = 3;

const containerStyle = { 
  display: "flex", 
  width: "600px", 
  flexWrap: "wrap" 
};

const itemStyle = {
  minWidth: `${100 / numItemsPerRow}%`,
  textAlign: "center",
  border: "1px solid black",
  boxSizing: "border-box"
};

const elements = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

const Grid = () => (
  <div style={containerStyle}>
    {elements.map(elem => <div style={itemStyle}>{elem}</div>)}
  </div>
);
```

[you can find a good tutorial on how to use flexbox here](https://flexbox.io/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I want to limit the number of items per row I'd then have to use percent width, right?

Comment: @mowtheone Exactly. It would be `100% / number_of_items_per_row` for the width of each item.

Comment: @mowtheone I created a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o9l84qvlly).

Comment: what would be the cleanest way to set up spacing between the items and rows?

Comment: @mowtheone There are multiple ways to achieve that. The cleanest solution (in my oppinion) is to set a margin on the children and a padding of the same size on the container. This way they will neutralize on the border of the container. I will edit my codesandbox.

Comment: @mowtheone I changed my mind about that :). The cleanest solution is to use css `calc()` to calculate the max width. See my updated codesandbox.

Comment: actually, this is not what i was looking for. now the padding is also adding spacing to the outer borders of the items :(.

Comment: @mowtheone Right, that doesn't work as I expected. I edited it again using negative margins. This should work.